# Am I allowed to teach my online students someone 's book?

Tags: copyright

Is it legal to teach my online students someone's book without getting the permission from the writer? I emailed him many times but he didn't answer me.

Comment: Is there any expectation that the students will purchase the book? Do you at least advise it?

Comment: I didn't advise it but I will do it because they need the book. I wrote the book's title and the author's name at the end of each lesson.

Comment: Does "on-line book" mean freely available for everyone from the author's website, for example? Does the author make any on-line comments about requested styles of use of the book? For example, I don't mind at all if people use my on-line stuff (both "books" and more fragmentary notes), without asking me, though of course I'd hope they'd not chop my name off the things and claim it as their own! :)

Comment: Thanks:). It is not an online book and no he didn't mention anything about this point.

Comment: Nothing specific to academia in this question, doesn't show research (Fair Use is very well known)

Answer (score 1):

Copyright is about copying, not about use. So, it is possible to do this if you use a bit of caution. First, though, you should ask the publisher about fair use in this case. The author may not actually hold the rights.

If you have learned from the book and teach what you have learned then you are probably fine. But if you give them sections copied from the book to read, say over the internet, then you are probably *not* fine.

Normally there is an expectation that the students have some access to the book even if they haven't purchased a copy. Borrowing a copy from the library or from a friend. So, an instruction to read Chapter 3 or do assignments 3.7 and 3.9 sends them to the copy for which they have access. None of that is copying and so is perfectly normal.

But if you send them a copy of Chapter 3 or even the literal assignments then you are on shaky ground. Ethically and maybe legally.

But you can make up assignments that are similar to those in the book, based on your own understanding. That should also be fine as long as you aren't being devious about just changing a value or two in a math exercise.

I'm hoping that publishers will be a bit more lenient than usual, given the current situation.

I'll note that copyright law varies widely around the world as does the definition of fair use. The creation of the Xerox Machine changed all of that and publishers have become quite stingy about such things. Your academic librarian almost certainly has guidelines about fair use in your country/region.

Comment: Why this answer is wrong, and the correct answer: https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/more-info.html https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/academic-and-educational-permissions/non-coursepack/ https://www.lib.uchicago.edu/copyrightinfo/fairuse.html (only bothering with examples for US law)

Comment: Hmmm @AnonymousPhysicist, maybe you should read it first. Not all educational use is fair. And the limits have been closing in recent years, not opening. Clearly you cannot distribute photocopies of someone's text book.

Comment: ...unless, of course the author/copyright holder gives you permission, either directly or by publishing the book under a license that explicitly permits copying.

Comment: @JeffE, yes, and I hope that publishers will be lenient in these times. A few are. The ACM digital library has been opened to all in the short term, for example.